# Is this a SPST Off-(NO) N/O NO Latching Push Button Switch

Tags: switches, button

[I bought this from ebay](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/181022376561)

expecting it to be the style of switch that when you push the button it connects the circuit until it is pressed again then it breaks it, like a ballpoint pen..

instead upon testing it, its a keyboard style switch where the circuit is only connected when it is pressed..

Is this a mistake by the ebay seller?
i was advised on this type of switch by someone here, at the exchange :)

(i was in belief that the keyword here is 'latching')

Thanks in advance

Comment: Off-(NO) makes no sense. Off-(On) would. The function in parenthesis is the momentary one. For example, a 3-position toggle switch with a momentary in one direction and non-momentary in the other might be denoted as On-Off-(On). NO means "normally open." The seller has used "N/O" and "NO" both to capture more searches, but they've re-used the term incorrectly for the position descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently were looking for a push-on, push-off switch. What you got was a momentary pushbutton switch that's normally open.

As per my comment, the "Off-(NO)" position description is a little incorrect; it should be "Off-(On)" which simply means the switch has two positions, off and on, but the on position is momentary, thus in parenthesis.

The seller also describes it as "latching" which should mean that a single push changes its position, and it stays there until the next push. Technically that would mean it's also ***not*** momentary, so the description is contradictory.

I'd ask the seller for a refund or replacement. I frequently order non-critical parts from Hong Kong or Shenzhen, China via eBay and generally have good results. Most of the sellers from those locations are *very* concerned about feedback and maintaining a good reputation, so you should get an amicable response.

Comment: Please add a comment when you hear the outcome!

Answer (score 2):

Actually switches are typically referred to as "momentary" for the type that you apparently acquired. The other type is commonly referred to as an "alternate action" switch. For push button types these would have an action, as you describe, similar to a ball point pen. The push button would operate as a push-on followed by push-off.

The eBay seller did list the item as a "latching" type push button implying that the switch was the push-push alternate action type. If that is not what you received then I would send the seller a message telling them that their description was wrong. Maybe they will be nice and replace the switch with the correct type. On the other hand the amount you spent was pretty low and is probably not worth getting into a contest about it.